# Google Cloud Function in Python gives an error on deploying

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to configure Google Cloud Functions to place an order when the function is triggered. 
I have mentioned `kiteconnect` in the `requirements.txt` file
But the function doesn't get deployed. throws an error "Unknown resource type".

FULL ERROR MESSAGE:

```
Deployment failure: Build failed: {"error": {"canonicalCode": "INVALID_ARGUMENT", "errorMessage": "`pip_download_wheels` had stderr output:\nCommand \"python setup.py egg_info\" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-wheel-97dghcl9/logging/\n\nerror: `pip_download_wheels` returned code: 1", "errorType": "InternalError", "errorId": "67DBDBF3"}}
```

Does anyone have any experience dealing with cloud functions to place a trading order on zerodah?

Following is the function that i have tried:

```py
import logging
from kiteconnect import KiteConnect

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

kite = KiteConnect(api_key="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")

# Redirect the user to the login url obtained
# from kite.login_url(), and receive the request_token
# from the registered redirect url after the login flow.
# Once you have the request_token, obtain the access_token
# as follows.

data = kite.generate_session("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", secret="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
kite.set_access_token(data["xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"])

# Place an order
def orderPlace():
    order_id = kite.place_order(
        variety=kite.VARIETY_REGULAR,
        exchange=kite.EXCHANGE_NSE,
        tradingsymbol="INFY",
        transaction_type=kite.TRANSACTION_TYPE_BUY,
        quantity=1,
        product=kite.PRODUCT_CNC,
        order_type=kite.ORDER_TYPE_MARKET
    )

    logging.info("Order placed. ID is: {}".format(order_id))
except Exception as e:
    logging.info("Order placement failed: {}".format(e.message))
```

Content of requirements.txt file:

```
# Function dependencies, for example:
# package>=version
kiteconnect
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: thanks. but there was no error message with Traceback. I could see the following in logs:
2019-11-05 12:40:02.628 IST
Cloud Functions
UpdateFunction
us-central:pl_ord
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com
INVALID_ARGUMENT

Comment: also found this:

Deployment failure:
Build failed: {"error": {"canonicalCode": "INVALID_ARGUMENT", "errorMessage": "`pip_download_wheels` had stderr output:\nCommand \"python setup.py egg_info\" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-wheel-97dghcl9/logging/\n\nerror: `pip_download_wheels` returned code: 1", "errorType": "InternalError", "errorId": "67DBDBF3"}}

Comment: all log messages put in question - they will be more readable. And other people will also see them. They may skip comments.

Comment: Please add the content of your **requirements.txt** file. Have you tested this code locally?

Comment: added requirements.txt content in question. I have not tested this locally.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that one of your dependencies is uninstallable.

It looks like the `kiteconnect` dependency is currently incompatible with Python 3.7, which is the Python version Cloud Functions uses in it's runtime: https://github.com/zerodhatech/pykiteconnect/issues/55

You'll need to wait until the maintainers release a new version that is compatible with Python 3.7.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It looks like this is the issue. Let me confirm this with the maintainers and then get back here.